# how to stop re-render html when we use this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value)?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to stop re-render html when we use (this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value)) in 
    angular 5+?

Comment: Thanks! we've hade a similar issue and this q/a helped us to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a pipe to have the job done. In theory, the pipe will cache the results and return the same value as you pass the same argument:

In safe-html.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml' })
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

    public transform(value: string): SafeHtml {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    }
}
```

In your implementation:

```
<img [src]="image | safeHtml" />
```